# Provide MS Teams chat functionality in custom tab

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am building a custom application for microsoft teams. Where I want to have a tab with Chat functionality in it. Is it possible to have chat feature inside custom app tab ?

If yes, can someone provide step by step guideline for that?

Comment: You might be looking for this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/deploy-chat-teams-channels-microsoft-teams-landing-page

Comment: Hi @SigarDave - Could you please confirm are you building an personal tab or Teams channel tab?

Comment: I am building Personal tab

Answer (score 0):

Currently for personal tabs, there is no option to have a tab with Chat functionality in it.

we recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

But When a custom tab is added to a channel, a Tab conversation is created that allows team members to have focused discussions about the content as shown in below.

[image]